# How do you make a Vocaloid do a "hard" pronunciation for "Through"

Tags: voice, synthesizer

I'm working on this part of *Dance With the Devil* (Braking Benjamin)

> I can show you that, I can see right through all your empty lies

The vocaloid synthesizer Miku that I'm working with wants to pronounce "through"  *th r o--* ("soft" *th* and *r*), and I want to make *th* and *r* noticeable and have a consonant at the end to cut it off.

So...

*"Th R O-- (gh)"*

Instead of

*"th r O--"*

Comment: Is there any dialect or accent in which the _gh_ of through is pronounced?  Which consonant do you want it to have?  _F_ as in _enough?_

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be accomplished by creating an unregistered word and then directly editing the phonemes for it.

To create the desired custom pronunciation of "through", you would invent a nonsense word (say, "ZQX") and then specify the phonemes, which would be something like [Dru:] (IPA: ðɹu) plus your consonant of choice to end it.